# 'Framework' tab is empty in PHPStorm

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

I am using PHPStorm to develop a Symfony2 application. Everything works fine, but the 'Framework' tab doesn't show my controllers, resources and bundle contents.

It should be like this:
http://www.kevwebdev.com/img/2012/11/phpstorm-framework-tab.png

I have this: 
http://pl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2dsls08&s=8#.U7LuDPl_sqE

I have controllers in my project, but PHPStorm doesn't show them.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Did you try posting this issue on their support forums?

Comment: I write an e-mail, but I didn't get answer. Maybe I should post it on forum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to fix your project settings. Go to File->Settings->PHP->Framework Integration and make the necessary changes as shown in the screenshot below. To change a setting for a given directory, just click in the 'Element' column and you'll get a drop down selector with the available options.

[image]

Afterwards, everything should be working fine.

Comment: It was weird, but I have selected everything except the "project code directory". I selected this and everything is ok. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah, the UI is not quite straightforward. Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer. Cheers! :)